# How to convert a list of strings to ints ignoring non integers

Tags: linq, lambda, c#-3.0

I am used to writing C# without using Linq or Lambda statements, but I'd like to improve my understanding. I have code that looks like this written in C# 2.0 with a `foreach` loop:

```
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("1");
        strings.Add("blah");

        List<int> ints1 = new List<int>();
        foreach (string x in strings)
        {
            int r;
            if (int.TryParse(x, out r))
                ints1.Add(r);
        }
```

It's doing a simple task - populating a list of ints from a list of strings, ignoring any that aren't actually ints.
In my limited experience, Linq and Lambda statements seem to be able to cut foreach statements down into very succinct and readable ways of doing the same thing. So I thought I'd try this little one using C# 3.0. But the best I could come up with is this:

```
       IEnumerable<int> ints2 = strings.Select(x =>
                                     {
                                         int r;
                                         if (int.TryParse(x, out r))
                                             return r as int?;
                                         return null;
                                     })
                                     .Where<int?>(x => x != null)
                                     .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Yuck! I couldn't find a way to combine the converting and filtering in one call and ended up with something that appears to be much worse than the original. Is there a way of doing this or should I stick with my foreach?

**EDIT:** To summarise findings, here are 2 ways to do this with LINQ if you are using .NET 4.0:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints1 = strings
.Where(x => new Int32Converter().IsValid(x))
.Select(x => int.Parse(x));//Broken in .NET 3.5 due to bug in Int32Converter


IEnumerable<int> int2 = strings
.Where(x => { int r; return int.TryParse(x, out r); })
.Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```

The second method is faster and is not broken in .NET 3.5. And there is probably no reason not to put this inside an extension method, as per the accepted answer, instead of the foreach.
See [connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93559/typeconverter-for-value-types-such-as-int-bool-short-etc-return-true-to-isvalid-even-if-the-value-is-not-valid) for the `Int32Converter` bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define my own extension method as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AsIntegers (this IEnumerable<string> strings) {
   foreach (var s in strings) {
      int r; if (int.TryParse (s, r)) yield return r;
   }
}

...

List<int> intList = new List (stringList.AsIntegers ());
```

or

```
var intList = stringList.AsIntegers ().ToList ();
```

Comment: This is readable and succinct. But if performance could be an issue then see the tests run by @Matteo

Answer (score 3):

you can do that with a simple linq

```
int num = 0;
var ints = (from str in strings
            where int.TryParse(str,out num)
            select num).ToList();
```

Comment: That's amazing, and slightly terrible.

Comment: it creates trouble when used in parallel. I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Colin I imagine you could `TryParse` another `str` before you've `select`ed `num` from a previous `TryParse`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get only `int` using **LINQ** is:

```
var integerList =
    strings
        .Where(x => new Int32Converter().IsValid(x))
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```

[Update]

I did a [performance test](http://linqpadsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Benchmark%20class%20for%20performance%20tests) using LINQPad.

Here I report the code and the result:

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "1", "a", "3", "b" };

    Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<int>> func1 =
        list => list.Where(x => new Int32Converter().IsValid(x)).Select(x => int.Parse(x));

    Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<int>> func2 =
        list => { var ret = 0; return list.Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out ret)).Select(x => ret); };

    Benchmark
        .For(1000)
            .Execute("Int32Converter", () => func1(strings).Iterate())
            .Execute("int.TryParse", () => func2(strings).Iterate())
        .Report(4).Dump();
}
```

The `int.TryParse` is about 165 times faster than `Int32Converter`.

[Update 2]

The `TypeConverter.IsValid` inherited by the `Int32Converter` class contains a [bug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tez461eb) fixed in .NET 4.0.

Comment: How much faster? How does foreach compare? And does it avoid the  trouble when used in parallel?

Comment: It's 165 times faster.

I didn't no try, but you can find my snippet on [CodePlex](http://linqpadsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Benchmark%20class%20for%20performance%20tests) and modify it.

Comment: I got a hold of LINQPad and tried the snippet. But I get "Input string was not in a correct format." from the int.Parse. If I change all the strings to ints then 166% faster....

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I added the foreach and the results. But to get the results I had to change the inputs to integers because `Int32Converter` fails if strings passed in.

Comment: @Colin I tried again, the method Int32Converter.IsValid works well for numbers but also for generic strings.

Comment: I can't get this snippet to run in LINQPad. Sorry it's the int.Parse that fails. "Input string in wrong format"

Comment: The `int.Parse` fails because in your case, difficult to say why, `Int32Converter.IsValid` always returns true.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11870/discussion-between-matteo-migliore-and-colin)

Answer (score 1):

Just like that:

```
from s in strings
let parsed = s.TryParseInt32()
where parsed != null
select parsed.Value;

public static int? TryParseInt32(this string str)
{
    int i;
    if (!int.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out i))
        return null;
    return i;
}
```

The TryParseInt32 extension is reusable.

Here is an alternative:

```
from s in strings
select s.TryParseInt32() into parsed
where parsed != null
select parsed.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got some helper method like this

```
public static class CollectionUtilities {
    public static IEnumerable<int> ParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source) {
        return ParseInt32(source, NumberStyles.Integer, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int?> TryParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source) {
        return TryParseInt32(source, NumberStyles.Integer, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> ParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source, IFormatProvider provider) {
        return ParseInt32(source, NumberStyles.Integer, provider);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int?> TryParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source, IFormatProvider provider) {
        return TryParseInt32(source, NumberStyles.Integer, provider);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> ParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source, NumberStyles style) {
        return ParseInt32(source, style, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int?> TryParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source, NumberStyles style) {
        return TryParseInt32(source, style, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> ParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        return ParseInt32Iterator(source, style, provider);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int?> TryParseInt32(this IEnumerable<string> source, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        return TryParseInt32Iterator(source, style, provider);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> ParseInt32Iterator(this IEnumerable<string> source, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) {
        foreach (string element in source) {
            yield return int.Parse(element, style, provider);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int?> TryParseInt32Iterator(this IEnumerable<string> source, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) {
        foreach (string element in source) {
            int value;
            bool success = int.TryParse(element, style, provider, out value);
            yield return success ? (int?)value : null;
        }
    }
}
```

With these helpers you code would look like:

```
var ints = strings.TryParseInt32().Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```